# When will the subgroup generated by two sugroups be the product of two subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G = HD$ be a group with $H \leq G$ and $D \unlhd G$. Suppose that $d\in D$ and denote $K = \langle H, H^{d}\rangle$ and $B = D \cap K$. I need to show that $K = HB$

Since $H \leq K$ and $G= HD$, it follows that $B \unlhd K$, so that $HB \leq K$

I can't seem to show that $K\leq HB$. Clearly $H \leq HB$. If I show that $H^{d} \leq HB$ I would be done

Comment: There is something wrong.  From your definitions, we have $HB = H$, and clearly it is not necessarily true that $K \le H$. I wonder if you meant $B = D \cap K$?

Comment: If you define $B = D \cap K$, then an element of $H^d$ has the form $d^{-1}hd$ and since $G=HD$, we get $d^{-1}hd = h'd'$ and then $d' \in D \cap K$, so $H^d \le HB$ as required.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes thank you for picking up that typo precisely. $B = D \cap K$